# How do i submit a form using get method in third party url using jquery and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to submit  a form using ajax with GET method in my word press project.

i tried two method but that not work for me there is any problem in my code.

Method-1 Using $.get

```
$.get( "http://**.70.120.**/web/sms.aspx", { fullname: "John", contactnumber: "123333",Email_ID:"aniruddha@thinkbar.in",State:"MP",City:"Indore",Magma_Customer:"YES",Proposal_Number:"1234567890",Service_type:"CASE",Query_Type:"Test type",Message:"Hellotesting" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  })
  .fail(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data NOT Loaded: " + data );
     });
```

Method-2 using Ajax

```
     $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://**.70.120.**/webleads/sms.aspx",
  data: {fullname: "John", contactnumber: "123333",Email_ID:"aniruddha@thinkbar.in",State:"MP",City:"Indore",Magma_Customer:"YES",Proposal_Number:"1234567890",Service_type:"CASE",Query_Type:"Test type",Message:"Hellotesting" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {

    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  }) 

  .fail(function( msg ) {

    alert( "Data NOT Saved: " + msg );
  })
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://**.70.120.**/webleads/sms.aspx',
    data: {
        'fullname': 'John', 
        'contactnumber': '123333',
        'Email_ID': 'aniruddha@thinkbar.in',
        'State': 'MP',
        'City': 'Indore',
        'Magma_Customer': 'YES',
        'Proposal_Number': '1234567890',
        'Service_type': 'CASE',
        'Query_Type': 'Test type',
        'Message': 'Hellotesting'
    },
    dataType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function(response) { 
        console.log( response );
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log( errorThrown );
    },
});
```

the url that will be submitted on your server will be `http://**.70.120.**/webleads/sms.aspx/?fullname=John&contactnumber=123333&Email_ID=aniruddha@thinkbar.in&State=MP&City=Indore&Magma_Customer=YES&Proposal_Number=1234567890&Service_type=CASE&Query_Type=Test%20type&Message=Hellotesting`

Comment: Thanks Silver, i used your code but its not working. Always  show in error function message,and i didn't get any error in my console.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    data: { fullname: "John", contactnumber: "123333",Email_ID:"aniruddha@thinkbar.in",State:"MP",City:"Indore",Magma_Customer:"YES",Proposal_Number:"1234567890",Service_type:"CASE",Query_Type:"Test type",Message:"Hellotesting" },
    url: "http://**.70.120.**/web/sms.aspx",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(msg){
      //some function here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks urfusion, but ist not work,my code not going in success function.
Please see my 2nd method using ajax

Comment: Finally i got the issue, there is some CROSS blocked issue in third party API.

Comment: Glad to know you fix it.